# Sealing porous basement common-wall for smells

Tags: insulation, spray-foam

Our unfinished basement shares an extremely porous cinder block wall with our attached neighbor. Because it is porous, smells transfer readily (ex cigarette smoke).

How can we seal this wall ***without using potentially toxic stuff like spray-foam that produces off-gassing***?

(Even if you believe that off-gassing is not a real issue, my partner would not accept that. We have two young toddlers and want to avoid any potential exposure.)

Thank you!

Comment: This is a *far* worse problem than a smell one, at least if you ask me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? This house was built > 100 years ago. The entire block is one of like, attached houses. To save on costs (back then), a proper brick mitoyen wall was used between every *pair* of houses, instead of between every single one. Obviously not ideal, but it's pretty common around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the olde-fashioned route and gypsum plaster the whole thing.

You could go new-fashioned and mud it with a skimcoat of drywall compound.

You could also slap up a layer of drywall first and then just tape and mud the joints. This might well be the cheapest & quickest option.

After checking VERY carefully for larger holes that might need something like ductseal or plaster to plug them, if the wall itself is really "porous" you could use a water-based "waterproofing" paint, such as UGL drylock (they have "paint" and "Waterproofer" - the former is thinner and covers more per gallon, the latter is thicker and covers less area - either might work but the waterproofer would be more like what you are asking for.)

You might need to caulk around the edges. You can get clear silicone caulk that is rated for food contact and aquarium use (check the fine print) and all it "gives off" is a bit of vinegar during a fairly short cure period.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking a layer of Type-X with the joints taped as air barrier seals would be the best bet for fixing this (it won't hurt the fire performance of the assembly).  I'm not sure why party/common walls in townhouses and duplexes are leaky, though...

Answer (score 0):

Sealing your side of the wall will not solve the problem; some humidity gradient is causing moisture to travel through the porous cinder block and into your basement. You'll have to seal off your neighbors side of the wall with a good quality moisture sealer. Sealing your side may result in the sealer bubbling and delaminating from the block. And like Ecnerwal said, check for air leakage too.